# Map Stream Get Total of Product of Key and Value

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Given a `Map<Long, Integer>`, using java 8 map stream, how do you calculate the total

sum of all Entries in a `Long result` variable?

For example:`[{100:1}, {100,2}]`

`result` = (100*1) + (100*2) = 300

This is how i do it using iteration:

```
Map<Long, Integer> map = //init map
Long sum = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    sum+= (entry.getKey() * entry.getValue());
}
```

Im thinking of something along this:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
.forEach(entry -> entry.getKey() * entry.getValue())
.sum()
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: I can do it using iteration ( non functional ), but im confused how to do this using lambda

Comment: Then post the iterative solution first. And try something using streams too.

Comment: Any attempt to solve it using java8 streams? Try that out and post the issues you encountered. Then we can help you.

Comment: @user1955934 try and use `mapToLong` and `sum` using streams.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick.

```
long sumOfProducts = map.entrySet().stream().mapToLong(e -> e.getKey() * e.getValue()).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for the same, here I have used java 8 stream reduce method :

Long totalSum= map.entrySet().stream().map(e-> e.getKey() * e.getValue()).reduce(0L, (s, i)-> s+i);
System.out.println("Total sum "+ totalSum);